# Translating 受け継ぐ as "released" or "inherited"?

Tags: translation, anime

How would you translate the following sentence?

> 今、千年パズルを解き闇のゲームを受け継いだ少年がいた。

I'd translate it this way:

> Now a boy has solved the millennium puzzle and inherited the dark games.

But in the English subtitles, they wrote the following:

> Now, the time where a boy has solved the Millennium Puzzle and released the Dark Games has come.

The verb 受け継ぐ is translated as "inherit, take over, be heir to" in these dictionaries: Kenkyusha, Riidaasu, eijiro.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the video? (Your translation looks good to me, btw)

Comment: I agree with choco, a video to verify would be nice and out of context it is hard to make a fitting translation. But your translation does seem pretty reasonable. 
Regardless of this specific situation, I've seen a great many bad anime translations done by both fans and on published material.

Answer (score 2):

Your translation looks ok, although, I like how the given subtitles phrase it, using "the time ... has come".

> Now, the time where a boy solved the millenium puzzle and inherited the dark games has come.

---

The quote is from [the opening of the first season of Yu-Gi-Oh!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PG7eyV5soA).

I believe the story holds some implication that the "shadow games" are *released* as a result of the millenium puzzles being solved. This is most likely the reason the translation uses the word released.

[The English dub can also be found on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cb3ggoyqXmU), and there, it is translated as following:

> Now, 5000 years later, a boy named Yugi unlocks the secret of the millenium puzzle. He is infused with ancient magical energies...

---

All in all, I think the translation should be a combination of what is faithful to the original, as well as what sounds good in the new language. Thus, taking a word that isn't verbatim in the original, but in the context, can be a good choice.